# How to show/hide button dependent on the position of content scroll in Ionic 2

Tags: html, scroll, ionic2

I want to show a button dependent on the different of current scroll position and the height of dynamic html content.

For example: if I'm in the bottom and the different of current position and content height less than 10px, then button should be hidden. else, it should be shown.

Comment: jQery and google will help you out

Comment: @Sand yes, u r right but I couldn't find bottom case for Ionic 2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the @ViewChild with Content component to get the position of your view.

**Your HTML**

```
<ion-content (ionScroll)="scrollFunction($event)">
  <!-- ALL YOUR CONTENT -->
  <button ion-button *ngIf="isShown">YOUR BUTTON<button>
</ion-content>
```

**Your .ts**

```
import { ViewChild } from '@angular/core'; // NEEDED IMPORTS
import { Content } from 'ionic-angular';

export class yourPageClass {
  @ViewChild(Content) content: Content;
  public isShown: boolean = false; // YOU CAN INITIALIZE IN FALSE SO IT DOESN'T THROW ERROR AND BECAUSE IT'LL BE ON TOP OF PAGE.

  constructor(){}
  //THE FUNCTION THAT'LL DO THE MAGIG
  public scrollFunction = (event: any) => {
    let dimensions = this.content.getContentDimensions(); // GET THE ion-content DIMENSIONS
    let bottomPosition = dimensions.contentHeight + dimensions.scrollTop; // THE contentHeight IS THE SIZE OF YOUR CONTENT SHOWN ON SCREEN, THE scrollTop IS HOW MUCH YOU'VE SCROLLED FROM TOP OF YOUR CONTENT.
    let screenSize = dimensions.scrollHeight; // TOTAL CONTENT SIZE
    this.isShown = screenSize - bottomPosition <= 10 ? true : false;
  }
}
```

So this way if your scrolled content + screen content is 10px smaller than the total height of your content the button'll be shown.

If you need to sho the button with more or less than 10px just change the 10 in `this.isShown = screenSize - bottomPosition <= 10 ? true : false;`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Exactly what I need.. thank u v.much my friend.. u always solves my problems

Answer (score 1):

I made a solution in ionic 4 based on Gabriels answer.

html file:

```
<ion-content [scrollEvents]="true" (ionScroll)="function($event)">
  <!-- ALL YOUR CONTENT -->
  <ion-button *ngIf="isShown">YOUR BUTTON<ion-button>
</ion-content>
```

ts. file:

```
export class page {
public isShown = true;

function(event) {
  const bottomPosition = event.target.clientHeight + event.detail.scrollTop;
    const screenSize = event.target.clientHeight;
    this.isShown = screenSize - bottomPosition >= -10;
 }
}
```

Hope it helps someone!

Answer (score -2):

You can simply use margin

```
<html>
<form id="hide">
<input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="show()">
</form>
<script>
function show() {
SCROLL DOWN*
```

SCROLL DOWN* : While button margin-bottom < 10px

```
var x = getElementById('hide');
x.setAttribute("style", "display:none");
```

I know this isn't the full answer, because I don't know script but it is a big help for you. Don't forget to use Google :)

Comment: Thanks, but your answer not related to my question.. Im asking about the scrolling of content and how to know if the content position in the bottom or not to show and hide the button